# Neo4j - Where to start, displaying on web?

Tags: web, playframework, neo4j, graph-theory

I've created a neo4j graph using Java, and it's sitting in an embedded database. What I want to do is write a web page which accepts user input, creates the graph using Java, and then returns the result to the web page, where it is traversed and displayed in a chart fashion.

I'm not sure where to start with this in terms of framework and how to query from root to all nodes in the graph. I was thinking of using play-framework.

What should I be looking for in terms of documentation to work out querying the graph using play, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: We're currently working on a play2 plugin for scala, and plan to release a preliminary version in the next week. Not sure how annoying it would be to use from Java, but it might give you an idea/starting point. https://github.com/AnormCypher/AnormCypher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use Spring Data Neo4j, probably the most convenient and most stable Java solutoin right now, see http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j